# Python to loop multiple times and print last file name in csv

Tags: python

There are 6 different file names in my folder (a0001, b0001, c0001)

The numbers are random and counting up, daily files coming in can be a0002, c0002, c0003, etc.

How do i create a loop that can loop through each name 'a', 'b', 'c'

and print the name of the files + last file name in csv

E.g.
A0001

A0002

A0003

Last file name A0004

B0001

B0002

Last file name B0002

**Current code**

```
file_name = <path>
headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Creation Time', 'File Name', 'First WB', 'Last WB', 'Last File', 'Missing File']
namelist = os.listdir<path>
ruta = <path>

now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


match = 'false'
if os.path.isfile(file_name):
  with open(file_name, 'a', newline = "", encoding="utf-8") as gemfile:
    writer = csv.writer(gemfile)
    
    for f in sorted(namelist):   
      filename = 'a'
      previous_filename = filename
      
      if filename == previous_filename:
        writer = csv.writer(gemfile)
        latest = <path> for x in os.listdir<path>
        newest = max(latest, key = os.path.getctime)
        name, extension = path.splitext(newest) 
        writer.writerow([""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [os.path.basename(name[-5:])])

      else:
        match = 'true'
        fullpath = os.path.join (ruta, f)
        ctime = os.path.getctime(fullpath)
        dt = os.stat(fullpath).st_ctime
        create = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)
        name, extension = path.splitext(f)

        writer.writerow([date] + [time] + [create] + [name[-5:]] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [""])
    previous_filename = filename
    previous_filename = 'a'
   
  gemfile.close()
```

**Working code (can print in excel but code fails when i tried to loop)**

```
file_name = 'path'
headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Creation Time', 'File Name', 'First WB', 'Last WB', 'Last File', 'Missing File']
namelist = os.listdir("path")
ruta = ("path")

now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

if os.path.isfile(file_name):
  with open(file_name, 'a', newline = "", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        
    for f in sorted(namelist):
        fullpath = os.path.join (ruta, f)
        ctime = os.path.getctime(fullpath)
        dt = os.stat(fullpath).st_ctime
        create = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)
        name, extension = path.splitext(f) 
        writer.writerow([date] + [time] + [create] + [name[-5:]] + [] + [] + [] + [])

#create new excel file if not found                          
else:
  with open(file_name, 'w', newline = "", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for f in sorted(namelist):
        fullpath = os.path.join (ruta, f)
        ctime = os.path.getctime(fullpath)
        dt = os.stat(fullpath).st_ctime
        create = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)
        name, extension = path.splitext(f) 
        writer.writerow([date] + [time] + [create] + [name[-5:]] + [] + [] + [] + [])

#last file name
with open(file_name, 'a', newline = "", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  latest = [os.path.join('path', x) for x in os.listdir('path')]
  newest = max(latest, key = os.path.getctime)
  name, extension = path.splitext(newest) 
  writer.writerow([""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [""] + [os.path.basename(name[-5:])])
```

Current code output
[current_code_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhkEj.png)